# Scrapy and xpath to crawl my site and export URLs - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to set up a basic Scrapy to crawl my website and extract all the page URLs of my site. I would think this would be fairly easy.

Here's my items.py, copied from the tutorial:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
class Website(Item):
    name = Field()
    description = Field()
    url = Field()
```

Here's my Spider, named example.py from the tutorial.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from cspenn.items import Website


class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "cspenn"
    allowed_domains = ["christopherspenn.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.christopherspenn.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//a')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['name'] = site.xpath('a/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('a/@href').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
            items.append(item)

        return items
```

What I get in return from the bot is:

```
scrapy crawl cspenn
2016-04-13 13:15:25 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.5 started (bot: cspenn)
2016-04-13 13:15:25 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11, boto
2016-04-13 13:15:25 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cspenn.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cspenn.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'cspenn'}
2016-04-13 13:15:25 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-04-13 13:15:26 [boto] DEBUG: Retrieving credentials from metadata server.
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [boto] ERROR: Caught exception reading instance data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/utils.py", line 210, in retry_url
    r = opener.open(req, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [boto] ERROR: Unable to read instance data, giving up
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.christopherspenn.com/> (referer: None)
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.christopherspenn.com/>
{'description': [], 'name': [], 'url': []}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 222,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 14302,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 13, 17, 15, 27, 262789),
 'item_scraped_count': 93,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 96,
 'log_count/ERROR': 2,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 13, 17, 15, 27, 77084)}
2016-04-13 13:15:27 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

What am I doing wrong? I followed the tutorial almost exactly. The desired output is a CSV file of title, page URL, and description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not making context-specific xpaths correctly. You already have the `a` in the context, inside the `site` variable, no need to prepend `a` to the XPath expressions inside the loop:

```
sel = Selector(response)
sites = sel.xpath('//a')
for site in sites:
    item = Website()
    item['name'] = site.xpath('text()').extract()
    item['url'] = site.xpath('@href').extract()
    item['description'] = site.xpath('text()').re('-\s[^\n]*\\r')
    yield item
```

And, since you have the empty descriptions in the output as well, I suspect the regular expression needs to be tweaked too. This though depends on what exactly are you trying to extract from the link texts.

Comment: I'm basically looking for a clean export of the entire site's URLs. Crawl a whole site and export all the page URLs. Thank you!

Comment: @ChristopherPenn okay, let's approach it step by step, what output are you getting now? Do you now see the non-empty `name` and `url`?

Comment: I do! 

    {'description': [],
    'name': [u'Marketing White Belt'],
    'url': [u'http://www.christopherspenn.com/buy-the-marketing-white-belt-book/']}

Comment: @ChristopherPenn okay, the major problem solved. Now, what do you want to see inside `description` fields? Thanks.

Comment: I actually don't care about it - the catch is that I thought this spider would traverse my entire site